# Returning JSON from Postgresql Timestamp fails in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am developing an application with Laravel 5.2 I need to return some `JSON` response from `Postgresql` database, but I am getting the following error (I posted the first lines of error message)

```
in Carbon.php line 425
 at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-06-07 10:06:23.701566') in      Model.php line 2958
 at Model->asDateTime('2016-06-07 10:06:23.701566') in Model.php line 2451
at Model->attributesToArray() in Model.php line 2428
at Model->toArray() in Collection.php line 1023
at Collection->Illuminate\Support\{closure}(object(Category))
at array_map(object(Closure), array(object(Category), object(Category))) in   Collection.php line 1024
at Collection->toArray() in JsonResponse.php line 48
at JsonResponse->setData(object(Collection)) in JsonResponse.php line 49
```

the records in database have 2 fields `created_at` and `updated_at` which both are `timestamp` type 
this is what is returned and printed by `dd()` function for one row

```
"id" => 1
    "name" => "category1"
    "description" => "category 1 decription "
    "created_at" => "2016-06-07 10:06:23.701566"
    "updated_at" => "2016-06-07 10:06:23.701566"
  ]
```

and this is my function in `Controller` `use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Category;

```
    class CategoryController extends Controller
   {

   public function index()
   {
    $categories = Category::all();


    return response()->json($categories);

   }
```

help me please through this issue how to get it working and also let me know if I have to provide any further information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Carbon is trying to format your date with:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-06-07 10:06:23.701566')
```

The correct format should be as below, which includes the microseconds.

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', '2016-06-07 10:06:23.701566')
```

Try putting this in your Category model file.

```
 protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I've already solved it with overriding the method  public function getDateFormat()
    {
        return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
    }